# Strange behavior in julia dictionary - keys can be printed but not found

Tags: julia, julia-jump

So for some reason I can print the keys of a dictionary and access elements of a dictionary in a loop but I cannot do it outside of the loop. Any advice as to how to fix this would be very much appreciated.

```
`nodedata_dict = Dict(pairs(eachcol(nodedata_data)))
counter = 0
for (key, value) in nodedata_dict
    if counter <= 2
    println("Key:$key, Value: $value")
    println(key in keys(nodedata_dict))
    println(nodedata_dict[key])
    counter += 1
    end
end

println("ok can we get this node right",nodedata_dict["pwpl_idno_12184"])`
```

Output is as follows:

`Key:pwpl_idno_12184, Value: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] true [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] Key:rwst_idno_1721, Value: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] true [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] Key:rwst_idno_2068, Value: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] true [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] KeyError: key "pwpl_idno_12184" not found`

So basically I can print out a few keys including "pwpl_idno_12184" but then when I try to access that key I get an error indicating that key that I just printed from the dictionary does not exist.

Comment: a DataFrame object. Think I fixed per the below now.

Answer (score 2):

ok I fixed this - the keys were Symbol type not Strings hence to call the keys I had to use :keytext instead of "keytext".